# Wait for data in mapstate to finish loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await, vuex

I have stored a `userProfile` in `Vuex` to be able to access it in my whole project. But if I want to use it in the `created()` hook, the profile is not loaded yet. The object exists, but has no data stored in it. At least at the initial load of the page. If I access it later (eg by clicking on a button) everything works perfectly.
Is there a way to wait for the data to be finished loading?

Here is how `userProfile` is set in `Vuex`:

```
mutations: {
    setUserProfile(state, val){
      state.userProfile = val
    }
},
actions: {
    async fetchUserProfile({ commit }, user) {
      // fetch user profile
      const userProfile = await fb.teachersCollection.doc(user.uid).get()
  
      // set user profile in state
      commit('setUserProfile', userProfile.data())
    },
}
```

Here is the code where I want to acess it:

```
<template>
<div>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  {{userProfile.firstname}}
  {{institute}}
</div>
</template>


<script>
import {mapState} from 'vuex';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      institute: "",
    }
  },
  computed: {
      ...mapState(['userProfile']),
  },
  created(){
    this.getInstitute();
  },

  methods: {
    async getInstitute() {
      console.log(this.userProfile); //is here still empty at initial page load

      const institueDoc = await this.userProfile.institute.get();
      if (institueDoc.exists) {
        this.institute = institueDoc.name;
      } else {
        console.log('dosnt exists') 
      }
      
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Through logging in the console, I found out that the problem is the order in which the code is run. First, the method `getInstitute` is run, then the `action` and then the `mutation`.
I have tried to add a `loaded` parameter and played arround with `await` to fix this issue, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you make `created` or `mounted` async, they won't delay your component from rendering. They will only delay the execution of the code placed after `await`.

If you don't want to render a portion (or all) of your template until `userProfile` has an `id` (or any other property your users have), simply use `v-if`

```
<template v-if="userProfile.id">
  <!-- your normal html here... -->
</template>
<template v-else>
   loading user profile...
</template>
```

---

To execute code when `userProfile` changes, you could place a [watcher](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#watchers) on one of its inner properties. In your case, this should work:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    institute: ''
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['userProfile']),
  },
  watch: {
    'userProfile.institute': {
      async handler(institute) {
        if (institute) {
          const { name } = await institute.get();
          if (name) {
            this.institute = name;
          }
        } 
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  }
}
```

---

Side note: Vue 3 comes with a built-in solution for this pattern, called [Suspense](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/packages/runtime-core/src/components/Suspense.ts#L81). Unfortunately, it's only mentioned in a few places, it's not (yet) properly documented and there's a sign on it the API is likely to change.
But it's quite awesome, as the rendering condition can be completely decoupled from parent. It can be contained in the suspensible child. The only thing the child declares is: *"I'm currently loading"* or *"I'm done loading"*. When all suspensibles are ready, the template default is rendered.
Also, if the children are dynamically generated and new ones are pushed, the parent suspense switches back to fallback (loading) template until the newly added children are loaded. This is done out of the box, all you need to do is declare `mounted` async in children.
In short, what you were expecting from Vue 2.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't solve all of my problems. I need the method `getInstitute` to be excecuted when `userProfile` is loaded to get some more information I need to display. Is there a way to do that?
Thank you also for the information about `<Suspense>`. Really cool!

Comment: @Sumny, that can be done in a `watch` (updated the answer). But why aren't you firing the extra code from where you're receiving the `userProfile` response? You can simply place it in a different action and dispatch it.

Comment: @tao Thank you. I tried it in the store, but it did not work because I need this again to be availible in the created hook.
Actually, my problem is really simple: Every user is linked to one institute. In my firebase backend, I have different collections per institut: eg "insitut1_events" and "institut2_events". And I now need to set the right collection according to the user somewere. I just cant figure out how this could work

Comment: If you ***need*** some data in `created` hook you just don't render the component until you get that data. In your app component (or any parent component of your choice) place a *"loading data..."* div. Make the call. When it resolves, push it to store and with a simple `v-if/v-else` switch between *"loading..."* div to whatever it is you want to render with that data.